# Using a Calculator to Confirm Euler's Identity

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, exponentiation

Euler's Formula is:
$$e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$$

If $x=\pi$, then I should get $-1$ for $\cos(x)$ and $0$ for $\sin(x)$, and yet, when I use the calculator, I get about $0.9985$ for the cosine of $\pi$, and $0.0548$ for the sine of $\pi$, whether I use the calculator in my computer or in my cellular telephone.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Are you perhaps inputting $3.14$ in degrees?

Comment: Make sure you calculator is set for radians and not degrees.  $\cos \pi = -1$ and $\sin \pi = 0$.  But $\cos 3.1415^\circ = 0.9985$ and $\sin 3.1415^\circ = 0.0548$.

Comment: There are three settings for doing trig calculations on most calculators  DEGREES, RADIANS, and GRADIANS.  A circular revolution is $360$ degrees, or $2\pi$ radians, or $400$ gradians and the values of $\cos,\sin$ will be based on what scale you use ($\cos \pi$ is supposed to be half a turn of a circle but $3.14^\circ$ is barely a 100th or a rotation. )  However I doubt either of you calculators are programmed for complex analysis and I doubt you will be able to enter $e^{\pi i}$ or $e$ to any non-real power.

Comment: I have to do it manually, and consider the unit of angle measure. As I commented below, the general Euler's formula should be e^{ix} = cos(Hx/ ) + isin(Hx/ ), if H is the measure of a half-circle (180 degrees,  radians, 200 grads, 2 quadrants, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing degrees to radians in your calculator.

Most Calculators have degree angle measurement by default!

Comment: So, to generalize the formula, it should be e^{ix} = cos(Hx/ ) + isin(Hx/ ), if H is the measure of a half-circle (180 degrees,   radians, 200 grads, 2 quadrants, etc.)

Comment: Yes, exactly. If H is the measure in degrees, then it is true. Because 180 deg = π rad, therefore H degrees = H×(180/π) radians.